# Powerbi DAX - I created a new table from multiple tables using SUMMARIZECOLUMNS but relationships break

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to create a new table that has fields from 5 other tables. These 5 tables are all related. I used SUMMARIZECOLUMNS to create the new table just fine. If I put all fields from the new table into a table visual, and then try to add a field from one of the 5 tables, I get an error saying PowerBI can't determine a relationship.

How can I create my new table and retain working relationships?